# WP8 App without Bindings at all?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am about to start developing Apps for Windows Phone 8 and doing the first steps (I already have some C# background with WinForms). But I realized that everything, especially XAML, seems to be so complicated. It's such a pain in the *** to do even the simplest things like populating a list. It does work with the a flat and extremely simple binding (as proposed in most tutorials), but that's just to stiff and inflexible.

I want to generate a list (LongListSelector) with items that contain these information  ("o" is each item):

```
<o.Name>
<o.TotalAmount> (<o.Things.Count>)
[if o.MiscThings.Count > 0]<o.MiscThings.Count> other thing(s)[/if]
```

Data examples:

```
John Doe
22.97 (3)
2 other thing(s)

Jane Doe
7.55 (1)
```

I tried to achieve this with:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="LLS_Summary">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalAmount} ({Binding Things.Count})" /> <!-- throws an error, concatenation doesn't work? -->
                <!-- well yeah this is obviously not possible with data binding -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>

// in .cs
LLS_Summary.ItemsSource = App.MyItems; // IList
```

Not even close. Concatenation only seems to work if I have some kind of converter beforehand and conditional things don't work at all this way.

So my approach would be to generate the elements on runtime myself. But how? The LongListSelector control doesn't seem to support this at all. In WinForms I'd do something like:

```
Label line1 = new Label();
line1.Text = o.Name;
Label line2 = new Label();
line2.Text = o.TotalAmount + " (" + o.Things.Count + ")";
Label line3 = new Label();
if (o.MiscThings.Count > 0)
    line3.Text = o.MiscThings.Count + " other thing(s)";
else
    line3.Text = "";

// sizing, positioning etc.

Panel panel = new Panel();
panel.Controls.Add(line1);
panel.Controls.Add(line2);
panel.Controls.Add(line3);

LLS_Summary.Controls.Add(panel);
```

How can achieve this in Win(P)RT? Is this even the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

A property can only have one binding, to achieve something like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalAmount} ({Binding Things.Count})" />
```

You can either use two text blocks, or use Runs and StringFormat

```
<TextBlock>
     <Run Text="{Binding TotalAmount}"/>
     <Run Text="{Binding Things.Count, StringFormat='{}({0})'}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about conditional text blocks?

Comment: At that point I would first look into things like Value Converters or if the changes will be vastly different then Data Template Selectors.

Comment: Value Converters are definitely the way forward, and are an intrinsic part of xaml databinding.  They help to seperate your logic from your presentation layer.